Is there any way I can make post requests using editorjs button?
I am using this editorjs button:https://www.npmjs.com/package/editorjs-button
So far I could make only get requests to the url endpoints ,is there a way in which I can make post request to an endpoint using this button?
Here is the github repo of the button:https://github.com/kaaaaaaaaaaai/editorjs-button

No, you can not make clickable link as non-GET request. Attach callback to make POST request or make that button submit form via POST

You can create a proxy. Send the GET request there, and turn it into a POST request (via curl for example) to the actual endpoint.
